# Overwrite files with `docker run`

Tags: docker

Maybe I'm missing this when reading the docs, but is there a way to overwrite files on the container's file system when issuing a `docker run` command?

Something akin to the `Dockerfile` `COPY` command? The key desire here is to be able to take a particular `Docker image`, and spin several of the same image up, but with different configuration files. (I'd prefer to do this with environment variables, but the application that I'm Dockerizing is not partial to that.)

Comment: Sounds like you want to use build args available in docker 1.9 up

Comment: I suppose if I use build args it doesn't rebuild all the intermediary containers? It just adds a new intermediary to the end and copies the file over?

Comment: Build args allow creating an image with x set to 6 and another image with x set to 7 from the same docker file. U then run containers from either image in the usual manner, I believe a common intermediary is used wherever possible

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a few options.  Using something like `docker-compose`, you could automatically build a unique image for each container using your base image as a template.  For example, if you had a `docker-compose.yml` that look liked:

```
container0:
  build: container0

container1:
  build: container1
```

And then inside `container0/Dockerfile` you had:

```
FROM larsks/thttpd
COPY index.html /index.html
```

And inside `container0/index.html` you had whatever content you
wanted, then running `docker-compose build` would generate unique
images for each entry (and running `docker-compose up` would start
everything up).

I've put together an example of the above
[here](https://github.com/larsks/example-for-breedly/).

Using just the Docker command line, you can use host volume mounts,
which allow you to mount *files* into a container as well as
directories.  Using my `thttpd` as an example again, you could use the
following `-v` argument to override `/index.html` in the container
with the content of your choice:

```
docker run -v index.html:/index.html larsks/thttpd
```

And you could accomplish the same thing with `docker-compose` via the
`volume` entry:

```
container0:
  image: larsks/thttpd
  volumes:
    - ./container0/index.html:/index.html

container1:
  image: larsks/thttpd
  volumes:
    - ./container1/index.html:/index.html
```

I would suggest that using the `build` mechanism makes more sense if you are trying to override many files, while using volumes is fine for one or two files.

A key difference between the two mechanisms is that when building images, each container will have a *copy* of the files, while using volume mounts, changes made to the file within the image will be reflected *on the host filesystem*.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  This is very helpful.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that in ```-v``` the first parameter is the local file outside of the container and the second parameter is the path to the file inside the container.  I was furiously trying your answer and didn't get it right until I flipped the two in my project.