# Overwriting files with -v in docker run not working

Tags: c#, docker

I saw this answer: [Overwrite files with `docker run`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705421/overwrite-files-with-docker-run)

I'm trying to overwrite the `test.txt` file that is built into the image with one on my local filesystem.

Here is the code I'm running.  There is a test.txt file copied into the image that says `This is the original file.`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ContainerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnumerateDirectory();
            DisplayTestFile();
        }

        static void EnumerateDirectory()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enumerating directory:");
            IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("./");
            foreach (string curr in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  " + curr);
            }
        }

        static void DisplayTestFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading test.txt: ");
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("./test.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
        }
    }
}
```

The `test2.txt` file on my filesystem says `This is the modified file!`.

The `Dockerfile` I'm using is:

```
# Use SDK
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

# Set the local working directory, copy in the project file, and perform a restore
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN ls -la 
RUN dotnet build   -f netcoreapp3.1 -c Release
RUN dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.1 -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .

# Set the entrypoint for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ContainerTest.dll"]
```

I'm building the image using the following, which builds without error:

```
docker build -t containertest -f Dockerfile .
```

I'm running the image, attempting to replace the original `test.txt` using:

```
docker run -v test.txt:/[path]/test2.txt containertest
```

However, when I run the image using this command, I still see the original `test.txt` file being used, i.e. it displays `This is the original file.`

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?  I know there are alternative solutions (docker-compose, etc) but I'm looking specifically to resolve this using `docker run -v`.

I've even tried building the image excluding the `test.txt` file and then mounting it into the image using `-v` and it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What host OS? How is Docker installed? What Docker version?

Comment: I figured it out...  The first parameter is the local file, the second parameter is the path to the file in the image.  ```-v /[localpath]/test.txt:/app/test.txt``` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The first parameter after `-v` is the local file (outside of the container).

The second parameter is the path to the file in the image.

In my case I had to use `-v /[localpath]/test.txt:/app/test.txt` and it worked.

Comment: Filed an enhancement on their documentation to reflect this: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11004